# how to do convert ft to cm and cm to ft in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to convert the user's height in cm to ft and inc values, and also to convert them to cm by selecting ft and inc values. I am sharing the parts I did, please help, I couldn't get out of the work.

For example, I enter 100 cm in the cm field and when I press the ft button, it needs to convert 100 cm to ft and it converts it to 3 ft 3 inches, in the same way, when I press the cm button again without changing anything, it should convert 3 ft 3 inches to cm, but 3 ft. 3 inches translates as 99 cm, in the same way, when I press ft again without changing anything, this time it is 3 ft 2 inches because it calculates over 99 cm and continues like this. I couldn't solve this problem, where could I be doing wrong, it shouldn't be like this?

**view**

```
   Button(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp),
                        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = toggleButtonBackgroundColor1),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(25.dp),
                        elevation = ButtonDefaults.elevation(0.dp, 0.dp),
                        onClick = {
                            if(!btnHeightIsSelected){
                                btnHeightIsSelected = true
                                btnFtIsSelected = false
                                isClickIn = false
                                isClickFt = false
                             
                                onFtToCmChange(state.ft.toInt(),state.inc.toInt())
                            }
    
                        }) {
                        Text(
                            text = stringResource(id = R.string.cm),
                            color = toggleButtonTextColor1
                        )
                    }


  Button(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(5.dp),
                        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = toggleButtonBackgroundColor2),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(25.dp),
                        elevation = ButtonDefaults.elevation(0.dp, 0.dp),
                        onClick = {
                            if(!btnFtIsSelected){
                                btnFtIsSelected = true
                                btnHeightIsSelected = false
                                onCmToFtChange(state._height)
                            }
    
                        }) {
                        Text(
                            text = stringResource(id = R.string.ft_in),
                            color = toggleButtonTextColor2
                        )
                    }



if (btnFtIsSelected) {
            CustomHeightScreenIncInputField(
                ftValue = state.ft,
                incValue = state.inc,
                ftPlaceholder = "ft",
                inPlaceholder = "in",
                onClickFt = {
                    onPickerStateChanged(HeightPickerState.FT)
                    isClickIn = false
                    isClickFt = true
                },
                onClickIn = {
                    onPickerStateChanged(HeightPickerState.IN)
                    isClickFt = false
                    isClickIn = true
                }
            )
        } else {
            CustomInputField(
                isFocused = inputFocused,
                placeholder = "your height (cm)",
                currentValue = state._height.toString(),
                onClick = {
                    onPickerStateChanged(HeightPickerState.HEIGHT)
                })
        }
```

**viewmodel**

```
fun onFtToCmChange(ft: Int,inc:Int) {

        //val cmHeight = (ft*12 + inc) * 2.54
        val totalInches = ft * 12 + inc
        val cmHeight = totalInches * 2.54

        _viewState.update {
            it.copy(
                _height = cmHeight.toInt(),
                ft = ft.toString(),
                inc = inc.toString(),
                height = "${cmHeight.roundToInt()}"
            )
        }
    }








fun onCmToFtChange(_height: Int) {

        val totalInches = _height / 2.54
        val ft = (totalInches / 12).toInt()
        val inc = (totalInches % 12).toInt()

     
        _viewState.update {
            it.copy(
                ftHeight = "$ft.$inc".toDouble(),
                height ="$_height",
                ft = ft.toString(),
               
                inc = inc.toString()
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what may be wrong with your code is that you are not using rounding functions at some points.

For instance line `val totalInches = _height / 2.54` should be modified to `val totalInches = Math.round(_height / 2.54)` and `val totalInches = ft * 12 + inc` to `val totalInches = Math.round(ft * 12 + inc)`

It is also important to use the math operators consistently, if you are using floor() in one function and ceil() in another you will also get inconsistent conversions.

Answer (score 1):

`.toInt()` always rounds down. You're getting rounding error when you go back and forth.

Calculating the conversion is so trivial, I suggest you keep it always stored in a single Double property and calculate the value for the current units on demand when the Composable wants it.

So, in your view state class, I suggest removing the properties for `_height`, `ft`, `inc`, `ftHeight`, etc. Just replace all of that with two properties, and you can add the other properties you need as ones that are calculated on demand:

```
enum class ViewStateHeightAppearance {
    Cm, Imperial
}

data class ImperialHeight(val feet: Int, val inches: Int) {
  companion object {
    fun fromRawCm(rawCm: Double): ImperialHeight {
      val wholeInches = (rawCmHeight / 2.54).roundToInt()
      return ImperialHeight(wholeInches / 12, wholeInches % 12)
    }
  }
}

data class ViewState(
  //...,
  val rawCmHeight: Double,
  val heightAppearance: ViewStateHeightAppearance
) {

  val cmHeight: Int 
    get() = rawCmHeight.rountToInt()

  val imperialHeight: ImperialHeight 
    get() = ImperialHeight.fromRawCm(rawCmHeight)

  val heightText: String
    get() = when(heightAppearance) {
        ViewStateHeightAppearance.Cm -> "$cmHeight cm"
        ViewStateHeightAppearance.Imperial -> with(imperialHeight) { "$feet feet, $inches inches" }
    }
}
```

I use an enum for the type of units so you can easily add other formats later without increasing code complexity.

With the above, you only have to change the `heightAppearance` when the user clicks a button. You only have to change `rawCmHeight` when the user enters different values. No extra step of doing a conversion every time the units change, and you never lose accuracy from changing the conversion back and forth because that doesn't change the stored value in `rawCmHeight`.

Comment: thanks for answer both of your answers worked.